# Ajax and Javascript - get filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

How can I get loaded filename? I have to put this instead of header, but I don't know how. I've tried to add additional parameter to xmlParser function, but actually it didn't work for me. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    doAJAX('LoadedFile1.xml');
    doAJAX('LoadedFile2.xml');
});

function doAJAX(url) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
}


function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();
    var myDate = new Date();

    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var n = 
                currentdate.getFullYear()
                + ("0" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                + ("0" + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2)
                + ("0" + currentdate.getHours()).slice(-2)
                + ("0" + currentdate.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
                + ("0" + currentdate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    var x = false;
    var y = false;
    $(xml).find("programme").each(function () {

        if ((parseFloat(n) > (parseFloat($(this).attr("start").slice(0,-6)))) && (parseFloat(n) < (parseFloat($(this).attr("stop").slice(0,-6)))))
        {   
            $(".main").append('<div class="header">HEADER</div><div class="programme"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div><div class="timec">' + n + '</div><div class="time">' + $(this).attr("start").slice(0,-6) + '</div><div class="time">' + $(this).attr("stop").slice(0,-6) + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("desc").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("category").text() + '</div>');
            x = true;
        } 
        else if ( x == true && y == true)
        {
            $(".main").append('<div class="programme"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div><div class="timec">' + n + '</div><div class="time">' + $(this).attr("start").slice(0,-6) + '</div><div class="time">' + $(this).attr("stop").slice(0,-6) + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("desc").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("category").text() + '</div></div>');
            x = false;

        }
        y = true;
        $(".programme").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the problem the file wasn't being loaded? can you try add / at the begining of the file?  doAJAX('/LoadedFile1.xml');

Comment: Does the xmlParser get called at all? Do you sess 404's errors in the console? How does the xnl look like?

Comment: File is loaded and data is parsed. I just need to know filename. So the data showed to user will be like this: LoadedFile1.xml, data parsed. LoadedFile2.xml, data parsed... etc.

Comment: Use Content-Disposition header to pass filename. I saw you wrote "I have to put this instead of header", I did not understand did you mean you dont want to use header

Comment: To precise: <div class="header">HEADER</div>, i wanna put it here instead of *HEADER* :)